# How to find the column key of Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [A] => Demo 1
            [B] => Demo 2
            [C] => Demo 3
            [D] => Demo 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => Sample 1
            [B] => Sample 2
            [C] => Sample 3
            [D] => Sample 4
        )
)
```

Find the column key like as (A,B,C,D)

Comment: Are your column names the same for each element in the array? Or are you trying to compile a list of all possible keys from your multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do it by merging by [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and then extract the keys by [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$res = array();
foreach($array as $sub) { 
    $res = array_merge($res, $sub); 
}   
$keys = array_keys($res);    
print_r($keys);
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of array_keys() function on each array element

[Manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach like this:

```
foreach ($stdTable as  $row) {
  echo "'".implode("','", array_keys($row))."'<br>".PHP_EOL;
}
```

OR

```
 foreach ($stdTable as  $row) {
     $keys='';
     foreach($row as $key => $value){
        $keys.= $key.',';
     }
     echo rtrim($keys,',');
 }
```

[image]